# how to retrieve data in select2, if the data stored in the database is the result of Json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

Hi there I have some problem, I have a problem, I want to display the data in select2, but the problem here is that the data stored in the database are the json's response This is the response I will take.

```
{
"name": "BCA",
"type": "bank",
"properties": "{\"data\": {\"id\": 1, \"nickname\": \"\", \"products\": [{\"id\": 1, \"number\": \"0011223344\"}]}, \"status\": \"success\"}",
}
```

i want to get **number** in select2

there is my select2 code

```
 $('#name').select2({
  placeholder: "Choose User...",
  ajax: {
    url: "{{ route('somemyroute') }}",
    dataType: "json",
    delay: 250,
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
          return {
            id: obj.user_id,
            text: obj.name+" | "+obj.properties.data.products.number
          };
        })
      };
    },
  }
});
```

but get some error like this jQuery.Deferred exception:

> Cannot read property **'number'** of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property **'number'** of undefined

Comment: your loop should be on products because products is array. replace data with data.products in map loop

Comment: and also make sure response is in object format.Now "properties": is in looking string format so you need to parse it using JSON.parse() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that all the data contains the products array. Some elements might not and hence you will get this error.

Also note, the products is an array of elements, so you'd want to reference which item from the array you'd want to select the number

Comment: I use laravel, and previously I did where so all the data that appears must have products and all the data is formatted like that, it's just different in number

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q30s2aok/1/ Note that I did have to change your datastructure to be a non-string "properties"